# Alter the Json data received using Model ExtJs

Tags: json, extjs

My json looks like below.

```
Message: {
  "totalCount":1,
  "responseObject":[{
    "mainTelePhoneNumber":"7702683320", 
    "name":"chinna"
  }]
}
```

The Model code:

```
Ext.define('FormData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'npa',
        mapping: 'mainTelePhoneNumber'
    },{
        name: 'customerName',
        mapping: 'name'
    }]
});
```

I am using the above model in my store. the listeners in the store is as follows.

```
listeners: {
   load: function(store, records, options) {
      if (records[0]) {
        formP.getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
      } else {
        //console.log("no data!");
      }
      gridForm.setLoading(false);
    }
}
```

but in my formP i have 3 textfields npa, nxx, xxxx. I have to split the data that i am getting in the JSON to parse the data to the form.

for Ex: the mainTelePhoneNumber":"7702683320", so it should be split to display npa:770, nxx:268 and xxxx:3320. Please help me how to do that using the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would use the convert method on the model field. This allows you to process:

```
convert: function (val, record) {
}
```

From which you can chunk your string.

[See Ext docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert)